# Foundations in Silverman's "Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves"

Tags: self-learning, elliptic-curves

I am currently self-studying elliptic curves using Silverman's AEC. I find his treatment of the background on varieties quite sloppy , and have so far kept going back and forth between AEC and Chapter 1 of Hartshorne, however having to translate between the 2, since their definitions are not identical. Is there an alternative?

Comment: I'm doing the same and I agree. However, I've always found Hartshorne impenetrable, so I'm looking forward to someone proposing an alternative.

Comment: Elliptic curves are the toy problem of varieties, I think the game is to translate   from $\Bbb{C}(x)$ (function field of Riemann sphere) to the complex torus (compact Riemann surface with obvious meaning of meromorphic functions and divisors and local ring) to the complex elliptic curve ($z\to(\wp_L(z),\wp_L'(z))$) then to algebraize the concepts so that they still apply to elliptic curves over $\Bbb{F_p,Q_p}$ and arbitrary fields. The degree of endomorphism, dual isogeny, invariant differential follow same idea, except for the non-separable degree and dual of Frobenius. @rogerl

Comment: My experience is that if you try to get a fully rigorous background on varieties first, then you will never get to the rest of the book in a reasonable time. Better to skim the background material on varieties, and take results from algebraic geometry for granted, to get to the actual material on elliptic curves.

Comment: @reuns I have a bountied question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3697090/endomorphism-rings-of-elliptic-curves-over-finite-fields) that it sounds like you could answer, if you're interested.

Comment: I think [Fulton's curve book](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf) has all the necessary results on varieties, and is *much* friendlier than Hartshorne. I think you can just focus on Ch. 2 to get enough background to get started, and then return to it if you find you need more as you continue in Silverman.

Answer (score 2):

If it is just about varieties, you could give *Mumford‘s Red Book* a chance. There also is *Garrity‘s Algebraic Geometry A problem solving approach* a friend of mine is very fond of. Personally I can recommend *Hulek‘s Elementary Algebraic Geometry*

Comment: I was going to suggest the *Red Book*. It's not a substitute for all of Hartshorne, but the treatment of varieties is more careful. Be warned that the later, Latex'ed, edition introduced tons of annoying typos.

Comment: Both the Red book and Hartshorne only talk about their varieties over **algebraically closed** fields. I understand that in order to remove this restriction, one can go to schemes in full generality. However, is there a good treatment of varieties over general fields? Silverman talks about varieties, not schemes, over general fields.